# Getting file path of an attachment in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to get the file path of an attachment so that its uploaded to vimeo directly from a `custom_post_type` in `Wordpress` but `$attachment_id` is returning a `null` . How can i get the `$attachment_id` ?

```
 global $attachment_id;
  $filepath = get_attached_file( $attachment_id ); 
  $url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos';
  $args = array(
      'type'=>'pull',
      'link'=>'the_link',
    );
  $response_vimeo = wp_safe_remote_post ( $url, $args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities depending on the situation you are trying to execute this code in. One possibility is

```
$post = get_post();
$attachment_id = $post->ID;
```

Or maybe the id is coming in from a `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable. Try adding `print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET);` and see what you get if you're submitting a form or creating a post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get  `$attachment_id`.   You have to provide  the `post_id`  which you want to get its attachments. And with help of the following code you can get all media attachments and with that you can get path of it.

```
    $args = array('post_type'=>'attachment','numberposts'=>null,'post_status'=>null,'post_parent'=> $post->ID // post_id is important. 
    );
   $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if($attachments){
          foreach($attachments as $attachment){
             // here your code 
              echo $attachment->ID; 
           }
      }
```

You can provide your code with in the for each to get each attachment of a post. If you wish to get all attachments than your `$args` variable should be like this.

```
        $args = array('post_type'=>'attachment','numberposts'=>-1,'post_status'=>null );
```

Comment: I have tried this before, this gives me all attachments in the database when all i need is 1 attachment of the 'active post' in my `custom_post_type`

Comment: If you specify the post parent `'post_parent'=> $post->ID`.  It will get you the particular posts attachments only